# Uploading images use Django Ckeditor --getting server error(500)

Tags: javascript, python, django, server-error, django-ckeditor

**Uploading images use Django Ckeditor --getting server error(500)**

I have been struggling for the problem for two days. Unfortunately, i still have no idea to solve it due to my poor knowledge. So i have to come here asking for help. Very appreciate ！

[image]

I want to write a website as my blog and use Django to implement it.
To develop this website, i have to use rich text editor, so i use CKeditor on admin panel. Here is the link of Ckeditor source code on github. https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

To upload images using ckeditor widget , i edited this file`../static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/image/di
alogs/image.js` so it can display the images upload button.

```
id:"Upload",hidden:!0
```

I also added upload url in `config.js`. After that, i set routing in the `urls.py` and added a view function in views.py. Everything was ok on my computer. however, after i deployed it to website server i got server error(500) during uploading a image by ckeditor . Ckeditor widget can not return the urls but i can find the images on server which i uploaded by ckeditor.

```
$:~/sites/www/source$ ls ../media/images/
20161219045646_7.jpeg           20161219053949_0094.jpg      
$:~/sites/www/source$
```

**config.js** (the location`static/ckeditor/ckeditor/`)

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2016, CKSource - Frederico Knabben.   All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl="/articleuploadimg/";
};
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from article import views as article_views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^articleuploadimg/', article_views.article_upload_image),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**The file tree**

```
|___sites
        |___www.mysite.com
                |___database
                |    |___db.sqlite3
                |   
                |___source
                |    |___manage.py
                |    |___article
                |    |      |___views.py
                |    |      |___...
                |    |___...
                |   
                |___static
                |    |___ckeditor
                |    |___css
                |    |___js
                |     
                |___virtualenv
                |___media
                     |___images
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from article.models import Article
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
import time

@csrf_protect
def article_upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        callback = request.GET.get('CKEditorFuncNum')
        try:
            path = "../../media/images/"+time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", time.localtime())
            f = request.FILES["upload"]
            file_name = path + "_" + f.name
            des_origin_f = open(file_name, "wb+")
            for chunk in f:
                des_origin_f.write(chunk)
            des_origin_f.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
        res = r"<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("+callback+",'"+file_name+"','');</script>"
        return HttpResponse(res)
    else:
        raise Http404()
```

**settings.py**

```
# Application definition    
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'article',
]
...
...

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'))

# Media files (upload path)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../media/'))
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = ""
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added something in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.mysite.com`

```
location /media {
    alias /home/XXX/sites/www.mysite.com/media;
}
```

as well as changed the path

```
path = "../media/images/"
```

Finally, it works !